# Unable to debug applet with JDK 7u21 and 7u25

Tags: java, debugging, applet, java-7, japplet

After upgrading my JDK from 7u17 to 7u21 or 7u25, I can no longer debug my applets. I used to set the following parameters to java.exe through Java Control Panel and it worked fine:

> `-classic -verbose -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Djavaplugin.classloader.cache.enabled=false -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8055,suspend=n`

However it's not working with 7u21 and 7u25. With Process Explorer, I see some debug-related parameters are missing in the command line:

> `"C:\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -Xbootclasspath/a:"C:\Java\jre7\lib\deploy.jar";"C:\Java\jre7\lib\javaws.jar";"C:\Java\jre7\lib\plugin.jar" -Djava.class.path="C:\Java\jre7\classes" -D__jvm_launched=602583525371 -D__applet_launched=602583523886 -Dsun.awt.warmup=true -Xdebug -verbose -Djnlp.packEnabled=false sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain write_pipe_name=jpi2_pid10980_pipe9,read_pipe_name=jpi2_pid10980_pipe8`

Should I change some parameters or Java settings? Or is this a JDK bug?

Comment: Try opening it with [Appleteer](http://pscode.org/appleteer/), an alternative applet testing environment.

Comment: Is the problem only happening in your browser?

Comment: I've tried Applet Viewer, IE and Firefox, and none of them works. Don't you have the same issue?

Comment: I have the same problem: Cannot remote debug an applet in Firefox from Eclipse, when using Java 1.7.0_25. Now I would like to debug with this version, because it seems to introduce another bug causing my applet to misbehave. :-(

Answer (score 1):

I had a LOT of trouble with applets in general with 7u25, and actually uninstalled it and went back to 7u21.  It was so bad that I submitted a bug report and Oracle is working on it.

I was able to get a decent amount of debugging with the in-browser Java Consoles by going into the Java Control Panel, clicking the Advanced tab, and enabling pretty much everything I thought might be relevant.

Comment: What bug did you submit to Oracle? I'm also suffered by this release. For example, `Applet.getCodeBase()` always returns `null` is I run applet locally.

Comment: @ZhaoYi Coincidentally enough (or maybe not), my bug boiled down to the fact that my program kept throwing a Nullpointerexception every time I tried to load in a local graphic when I ran the program locally even though the file was clearly there.  If you're having trouble finding a way to work around the issue, I found that AppletViewer still worked just fine for previewing my applet.

Comment: @ZhaoYi: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8017250 appears to be the bug report. At least it mentions this post here, including your comment.

Comment: @MvG That's actually not the bug that I submitted, but it's very close!  I'm glad to see that other people were having the same problem.