# Applet.getCodeBase() returns null for local Applets since Java 7 update 25

Tags: java, applet

Since **Java 7 Update 25**, Applet's method `getCodeBase()` seems to return `NULL` for local applets. I haven't found anything in **Java 7u25** release notes that would announce/explain this change, but I found an [email discussion](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.openjdk.security.devel/7894) which claims the change is actually intended.

Can anyone help me to find a resource/documentation where I could learn more about this change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

release notes are here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u25-relnotes-1955741.html

its in there.

"Local Applets return NULL for "

Comment: I am wondering how I could overlooked this... Anyway, it would be nice to know why this was changed the way it was.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE (1/21/2014): Java 7 update 51 appears to have fixed this Java bug

Oracle claims the fix was 'security' related, and was required to prevent a sandboxed applet from obtaining access to "file path" information (the folder name where the applet is being run).  But Oracle failed horrible, as explained in great detail here:

http://www.duckware.com/tech/java-security-clusterfuck.html

Google "java bug report" and submit a bug report to Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

[Oracle bug #8017250](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=8017250) (which apparently is related to [Unable to debug applet with JDK 7u21 and 7u25](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17206589/1468366) as well) has some more details. In particular, it states that this is “not an issue” (i.e. intentional) and suggests the following alternatives:

> If applet need to load resource:
>
> - if the resource is in applet JAR(s), they should be able to load it with [`ClassLoader.getResoruceAsStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) directly, without needing the codebase information.
> - if the resource is in arbitary location, not inside applet JAR, they should have other ways to get to that location, since it's not part of the applet resource anyway. (e.g.  `user.home` java system property, provided that their applet has all-permissions)